# Get variable from Ajax to Php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have ajax code which take textfiled variable. it alert the value, but when I want to get in php, it gives me an error of **Undefined index**

**JavaScript Code**

```
<SCRIPT>
function go(UserID) {
var name= encodeURI(document.getElementById('name').value);
var design= encodeURI(document.getElementById('design').value);
http.open('get', 'testAjax.php?design='+design+'&name = '+name);
http.send(null);
}
</SCRIPT>
```

**HTML Code**

```
<INPUT ID='name' type='text'>
<INPUT ID='design' type='hidden' value="<?php echo $UserID; ?>">
<A href="?process" onclick="javascript:go(<?php echo $UserID; ?>)">Link</A>
```

**Php Code**

```
if(isset($_GET['process'])) {
echo $_GET['design'];
echo $_GET['name'];   
}
```

please let me know how to solve it.

Comment: refer to search engine. Using jquery makes things easier.

Comment: Is that all your JavaScript code? You haven't created an xmlHttpRequest object here that we see. Also `get` should be uppercase `GET`.

Comment: Your go() function not have return false; this will make normal request to your php script. It mean that it make request as ?process without parameter. (You can check from developer tool in browser)

Answer (score 0):

You have an anchor tag on which you have an onclick event. Onclick event when fired will send an ajax request to `testAjax.php?` url.

However since you haven't prevented default behaviour of clicking an anchor tag, as soon as this ajax request is sent, page will redirect to `?process` and where ofcourse you will have nothing to receive as `$_GET` parameters.

Assuming you have your ajax going right, add `return false;` at the end of your `go()` function. Also since on server side you have a clause like `if(isset($_GET['process'])) {` , you should also update your ajax url to something like: `testAjax.php?process`

Comment: Thanks Abhinav.
so if I just send value with onclick function, and with no href, how can I get on php part. can you enlighten me with how can I retrieve back the value in php?

Comment: I changed whatever you said, now there is no error but also does not showing me anything when I echo $_GET['design'];
echo $_GET['name'];
although when I alert, it shows the text filed value in JavaScript part

Comment: your final ajax url will be like: `testAjax.php?process&design=some_value&name=some_name` ... after this if your server side php is entrying `if(isset($_GET['process']) {` loop you will also get values for `$_GET['design'] = "some_value"` and `$_GET['name'] = "some_name"`

Comment: My URL is like what you said, but it does not show me the variable. why is that?

Comment: inside `testAjax.php` try to simply see the output of `print_r($_GET);` , this should show you all key-val pairs (params) coming from client side to you. If you see params in there thank GOD, else even he cannot help :)

Comment: @user1328273 - you need to help us if you want us to help you. Show us your `$_GET`, as Abhinav asked.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a couple of things I spotted that maybe causing this issue.
Try:

```
<script>
    function go(UserID) {
        var name= encodeURI(document.getElementById('name').value);
        var design= encodeURI(document.getElementById('design').value);
        http.open('get', 'testAjax.php?process&design='+design+'&name='+name);
        http.send(null);
    }
</script>

<input id='name' type='text' />
<input id='design' type='hidden' value="<?=$UserID; ?>" />
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:go(<?=$UserID; ?>)">Link</a>
```

As you can see, we remove the html variable "process" and make it a part of the ajax call.